# Large Scale Watershed Delineation

Tags: qgis, saga, watershed, africa

Using QGIS,I attempted  Africa's watershed delineation taking the following steps:

- Downloaded DEM  from earthexplorer USGS  (GTOPO30)
- Created a mosaic of the downloaded DEM
- Reprojected the mosaic DEM to EPSG:54010 World_Eckert_ VI(For equal area world map projections)
- Rescaled map cell size to 1km by 1km(For faster processing time) using the Align Rasters function
- Filled depressions using   Wang & Liu XXL algorithm
  -Created stream order using strahler order function
- Choose  strahler order threshold using  raster calculator function
- Created the basins and channels using SAGA channel network and drainage basins function

The output (Picture 1) do not look satisfactory.

How do I improve the results?

[image: Africa_Watershed_Delineation]

The goal is to have a clearly delineated River Niger Basin- the basin with thickened blue border line in picture 2

[image]

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use HydroBASINS data.

Comment: Your streams look suspiciously straight and merge at 45 degree angles which are red flags for natural flow paths and suggests a 'bad' DEM that's unnaturally homogeneous.  That could be the result of some of your processing like the resampling or the fill.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the level-3 basins provided by HydroSHEDS

[image]

You can download these from http://www.hydrosheds.org/download (must create an account), or you can use this link for the next 3 hours: http://www.hydrosheds.org/tempdownloads/hydrosheds-209a52bb01dc03b64a9f.zip

Comment: At the tail end of the Niger River Basin lies my study area(Ogale, Rivers Nigeria). I need to know the sub-basin my  study area falls within. Therefore i have to determine the upslope area, River channels and flow directions using  suitable QGIS algorithms.

Comment: You should include extra details and constraints in your question. My answer provides a suitable solution for what you asked. You can simply intersect your study basin with the level-3 HydroBASINS product to find which sub-basin your study area falls within. There are other basin levels if you want a finer-scale watershed delineation.

Comment: I have tried  level-1-6 HydroBASINS product, i need a fine scale delineation.

Comment: It goes to level 12, which is quite fine.